# Why is my checkoutData object not initializing properly?

Tags: angular

I have the following data object:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CheckoutData {
    email:string;
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
    deliveryMethod: "Standard";
    paymentMethod: "Credit Card";
}
```

I inject the object in the constructor of my component and log it to the console:

```js
constructor(
    private store: Store<{ checkoutStore; cartState }>,
    public checkoutData:CheckoutData    
  ) {
    console.log('checkoutData constructor', this.checkoutData)
  }
```

It logs garbage instead of the instantiated data object:

```js
checkoutData constructor s {}[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Selecting radio buttons in my view than stores garbage in the data object:

```html
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="formCheck-3" name="paymentMethod"
        [(ngModel)]="checkoutData.paymentMethod" #paymentMethod=ngModel
        (change)="saveCheckoutData()"
        [value]="paymentMethod">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-3" style="font-size: 
    14px;">PayPal</label>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not a normal Object or Class, it's a Service therefore it's good practice to call it `CheckoutDataService`, but for solving your problem see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I can see is a typo in ur class.

Should be

```
export class HelloService {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  deliveryMethod = 'Standard'; //typo
  paymentMethod = 'Credit Card'; //typo
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-u9aztn?file=app%2Fhello.service.ts)